# Read bytes into array then xor the result into a string

Tags: c#, arrays, xor

I read bytes and display them in a text box with this:

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path));
br.BaseStream.Position = 0x1D; 
textBox1.Text = br.ReadInt32().ToString("X");
br.Dispose();
```

I need to read 4 bytes then XOR each one with the value 149 and print the results out to the text box. The text box only seems to display "System.Byte()"

I've tried this code, but there were many errors, such as not being able to convert a byte to an int:

```
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path));
br.BaseStream.Position = 0x3E8;
byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(4);
int i = 149;
```

The output should look like this:

```
result = buffer[0] ^ 149;
result2 = buffer[1] ^ 149;
result3 = buffer[2] ^ 149;
result4 = buffer[3] ^ 149;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. What is xoring?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: @AVKNaidu He probably means [^](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)

Comment: XOR = Exclusive Or.

Comment: Your given code do not print ` System.Byte()`

Comment: yes that's what I mean ^ I got working formula in excel

Comment: what I tried well all whats left from my tries and fails

Comment: BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path));
            br.BaseStream.Position = 0x3E8;
           byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(1);
           int i = 149;

Comment: uhh made a total mess there

Comment: `So can read bytes and display them in text box with this code` No this code read `CHAR` (which is not equal to `BYTE`)

Comment: my fault wrong code br.ReadByte.ToInt32(4).ToString("X");

Comment: again wrong br.readint32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, the land where dreams come true (if your dreams consist of answering programming questions.).  Since this is your first question, I'll do my best to answer but in the future, try to follow community guidelines to basically show that

1. You have tried to solve the problem yourself,
2. Post all code that is applicable to your problem, and
3. Explicitly say why the code you've posted isn't doing what you'd like it to do

As a side note, check out [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pyIr9K) when you want to make small programs to test out quickly.  Pro tip: don't use excel to debug c# programs ;)

## Answer: Daily Double

OK, I'm going to infer that your question is the following.  Pretty liberal paraphrasing I know, but I'm trying to help you out here

> [How can I read 4 bytes from a file at a given file offset, XOR each of those 4 bytes with 0x149, then display those on the screen?]

OK, first place to start is to get a `FileStream` object I think.  More reading: [what is `using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)?

```
using (var input = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    // somehow seek to file offset
    // read 4 bytes, and
    // XOR each byte with 0x149
    // store results in a List<byte> (or something)
}

// display result
```

Alright, to seek a file, you need [`input.Seek(0x1D, SeekOrigin.Begin);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) (Assuming 0x1D from OP is correct).

To read 4 bytes, do this (see [`ReadByte()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.readbyte(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation)

```
for (var i=0;i<4;i++){
    var byteThatIsNotRemembered = input.ReadByte();
}
```

Now you need to XOR those bytes with

```
for (var i=0;i<4;i++){
    var byteThatIsNotRemembered = input.ReadByte() ^ 0x149;
}
```

Finally, save them to a [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// need to instantiate list somewhere near top
var byteList = new List<byte>();

// ... other code that we've written

for (var i=0;i<4;i++){
    var byteThatIsRememberedNow = input.ReadByte() ^ 0x149;

    // need to cast to byte because ^ operator creates ints
    byteList.Add((byte) byteThatIsRememberedNow);
}

// you'll need to replace this with something for your text box...
// couldn't figure out from your question
for (var i=0;i<byteList.Length;i++){
    Console.WriteLine(byteList[i]);
}
```

All together now...

```
// need to instantiate list somewhere near top
var byteList = new List<byte>();

using (var input = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    input.Seek(0x1D, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    for (var i=0;i<4;i++){
        var byteThatIsRememberedNow = input.ReadByte() ^ 0x149;
        byteList.Add((byte) byteThatIsRememberedNow);
    }
}

// you'll need to replace this with something for your text box...
// couldn't figure out from your question
for (var i=0;i<byteList.Length;i++){
    Console.WriteLine(byteList[i]);
}
```

Here's a similar [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pyIr9K) where I use a string instead of a file to generate a stream.

Let me know if this was helpful

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about my post, or if you need any other questions answered.  I noticed that you want the decimal number display of a `byte`.  Just `byte.ToString()` will give you the decimal value of the `byte` object.

Comment: Your answer is helpful and gives me idea what to read more, idea was to read 4 bytes for example 92 3B 48 6B, if I read them by my first try I was not getting it right not even close to it, what I was wanting to get is represent various excel formulas in c#, (BITXOR((HEX2DEC(D6)),149)) so 92 in dec should be 146 and xoring it with 149 should give me 5 and so on and than display it all in textbox like 5555. So will walk thrue your code and will try to manage something

Comment: @domsrt I'm a little confused by your response.  First, your formula doesn't have balanced parentheses, but I'm assuming you mean "BITXOR((HEX2DEC(D6),149)".  If that's the case, I think you've confused something.  XORing values doesn't depend on how the numbers are displayed on your computer.  XOR _always_ **_always_** uses the 1's and 0's of the number to compute the answer, regardless of if you're viewing the number in decimal or hex, or binary, or octal, or base pi, etc.  I think in excel using HEX2DEC(...) _may_ be needed (not sure, but this is my guess) ...

Comment: @domsrt ... because the cell is a string (series of letters), and excel needs to interpret it as a number.  In C# all numbers are numbers.  Don't confuse the value of a number by how it's displayed.  EDIT: I've confirmed that [HEX2DEC(...)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HEX2DEC-function-8c8c3155-9f37-45a5-a3ee-ee5379ef106e) takes quoted values as input, which means a string.  The output is a string, as well, it looks like.

Comment: @domsrt I made this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0s4M1i) in case you wanted to see something that resembles your excel formula in C#.  It turns out that 146 ^ 149 is 7, not 5, like you said in your comment above.

Comment: great I run your code just had to add Console.ReadKey(); to keep cmd open and it works like it should, thank you very much for code I will try  to convert it to form application with txt box for input and output

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
using (var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path)))
{
    br.BaseStream.Position = 0x1D;
    byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes(4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] ^ 149);
    }

    textBox1.Text = new string(bytes.Select(Convert.ToChar).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: well it does job but result is bunch of characters charaters, I was trying to readbytes in decimal not hex or ascii and than xor each one with 149 and get result in format like 1234, will try to look at options and in msdn I could be missing something

Comment: Try `textBox1.Text = string.Join(", ", bytes);`.